# Background Image not Displaying in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, background-image

I am having the hardest time getting my background image to show in Chrome. The background image will display in other browsers, just not Chrome. I've seen other solutions on StackOverflow and similar sites, and have tried them with no success.

For example, I disabled extensions and removed the property "absolute" or set it to "static." I double, triple, quadruple checked whether or not the file existed and if my CSS was pointing to the file. It is, otherwise I don't think it would work in any other browser either. I added display: inline-block, but that did nothing.

For giggles, I also removed width, height, and top to see if that solved anything. Naturally doing so did nothing but cause the background image to stop working in other browsers too.

When I launch my site in Chrome, Chrome shows that something should be there but it doesn't display anything - not even a broken image icon. Any help with this conundrum would be greatly appreciated. Please see my code below:

```
 header a.logo {
    background: url("images/CC_logo.svg") no-repeat center top;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the site?

Comment: Maybe chrome have problems with SVG background. I found some discussion pages on google about problems with SVG background in chrome, and they can have various causes. 
[link](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/svgs-not-displaying-in-chrome)
[link](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/svg-css-background-image-not-showing-in-chrome/)
Its hard to  guess why its not working. Try to make demo in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: So you are facing this issue in chrome only?

Comment: Hi @Hopper, yes it is in Chrome only. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line to your **.htaccess**, so the server can recognize svg files from your css file (background: url("images/CC_logo.svg") no-repeat center top;), Insert this line:

```
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|svg|bmp|png|css|pdf|swf|mp3|mp4|3gp|flv|avi|rm|mpeg|wmv|xml|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|csv|ppt|pptx|zip|rar|mov)$ index.php
```

No need to have so many rules as above but depends on what you need for the format you would like to have on your site, but for your current question here, please make sure there is "**svg**" in the rule of your .htaccess file.

It works, try it!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your SVG was exported properly. I've found problems with Photoshop images exported as SVGs but I've never had an issue with Illustrator files exported as SVGs.

Comment: Thank you! It was definitely Photoshop that was giving me an issue. I also tried the code mentioned by Raymond Gintag with the older Photoshop .svg files, and that also fixed the issue. Looks like there are a few workarounds here!